# Passing the text to function on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please see the following code:

```
function liReplace(txt) {
    $('#srch > a').text(txt);
}


<ul class="dropdown">
    <li id='srch'>
        <a href="#">All Categories</a>
        <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Gadgets</a>
                <ul>
                    <li onclick='liReplace("DVD")'><a href="#" >DVD</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">XBOX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ps2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cellphone</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Locations</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I wanted to remove the code `onclick='liReplace("DVD")'` and change it to jquery.

I could use the class="dropdown" to identify it. How do I code and call the clicking of `<li>` tags inside that ul "dropdown" and pass the text?

i was thinking like

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $("li").val(this.text);

});
```

I know its very wrong, my excuse is that I am still in learning phase.

---ANSWER

```
$("ul.dropdown li > a").click(function () {
        var old_text = $(this).text();
        liReplace(old_text);
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$("li").val(this.text);` use `$('#srch > a').text(txt);`. The body of your event handler stay the same. Why would you change it? Also, `.val` only works on form elements: http://api.jquery.com/val/.

Comment: how do I set jquery click to li's of #srch only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function liReplace(txt) {
    $('#srch > a').text(txt);
}


$("li a").click(function () {
    var old_text = $(this).text();
    liReplace(old_text);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you update and undelete your previous brilliant answer?

Comment: Apologies, it wasn't me. It was my stupid office mate. Sorry again.

Comment: @timidboy Be careful, you might be banned for such jokes.

Comment: thanks @timidboy despite on calling me stupid. Appreciate your answer. thanks! thanks!

Comment: @Sid Your welcome. Big mistake I left my laptop unlocked :(

Comment: How do I fix the selector though. to only run click when <ul class="dropdown">

Comment: Like this `$("ul.dropdown > li > a")`

Comment: $("ul.dropdown li > a").click(function () {
  var old_text = $(this).text();
  liReplace(old_text);
 }); this worked

Answer (score 3):

Something like that should work:

```
$(".dropdown .sub_menu ul li").on("click", function() {
    $("#srch > a").text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. this keeps appending. For example, I wanted to change "All Categories" to "DVD" when I click "DVD"

Comment: @Sid Yes, it should do the job.

Comment: By the way , i tried all the codes here. I changed yours to.. 
$('ul.dropdown').click(function () {   
  $("#srch > a").text($(this).text());
});

Just so I could try them all. Yours however is Appending wildly. like  the whole (this).text is the whole LI

Comment: @Sid: The problem is that you have nested `li`s which is not considered with this selector.

Comment: @Sid `$('ul.dropdown')` means you select the `<ul>` element itself. Then you bind the click event to it, while you need to bind the event to nested `<li>` elements, not to the `<ul>`.

Comment: kind of.. thanks. I got the code working with $("li a").click(function () selector. but somehow I am guessing that when I have lots of li, my page would be in a mess... And I do have lots of li. this Li just goes to my dropdown. I dont want the others to behave thesame.

Comment: @VisioN yes but How do I fix your selector? it doesnt work when I use it. thanks by the way

Answer (score 2):

Try with -

```
<li title='DVD'><a href="#" >DVD</a></li>


$("li").click(function () {

    $(this).find('a').text($(this).attr('title'));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just select li with ul class name like this

```
    $('ul[class="dropdown"] li').click(function () {

       $(this).find('a').text($(this).attr('title'));

     });
```

Comment: => `ul[class="dropdown"]` <= Wow!

Comment: @G.R. I guess, the second or may be first most used selector of jQuery is class selector. `$('ul.dropdown')`

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$('li').live('click', function(){
    $('#srch > a').text($(this).text());   
});
```

or

```
$('li').click(function (){
    $('#srch > a').text($(this).text());   
});
```

Comment: What's this ? Have you read the question ?

Comment: Note that `live` is deprecated you can replace it with `on`.